# Compare strings in two lists of dicts : python-binance

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

Python-binance - find currencies that have both USDT and BUSD markets.

I want to make my code compare the USDT and BUSD market books and only return currencies that are in both markets.

The search_BUSD/search_USDT functions return a list of dictionaries.

'''

```
[{'symbol': 'BNBBUSD', 'bidPrice': '213.00000000', 'bidQty': '111.38000000', 'askPrice': '213.10000000', 'askQty': '65.38800000'}, .......
```

'''

```
market_book = client.get_orderbook_tickers()

def search_USDT(market_book):
    return [element for element in market_book if element['symbol'].endswith('USDT')]

def search_BUSD(market_book):
    return [element for element in market_book if element['symbol'].endswith('BUSD')]

for element in search_USDT(market_book):
    print(element['symbol'], element['symbol'][:-4])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
usdt = search_USDT(market_book)
busd = search_busd(market_book)
result = set()

for currency in usdt:
    if currency != 'symbol' and currency in busd.keys():
       result.add(currency)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work:
I got a AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: Sorry, just remove .keys()